# Clarification on Euler-Lagrange equation derivation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Below is extracted from page 8 of https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/44170:

[image: of]

I have an issue with the line:  "It is easy to see that this means both terms on the RHS must vanish...".  I.e. I don't see why the first term of the RHS can't just be the negative of the other.

Comment: This is supposed to be true for all functions $\eta$ so what happens to the first term when $\eta (a)=\eta (b) = 0$ but arbitrary otherwise?

Comment: @AHusain The assumptions that $\eta (a)=\eta (b) = 0$  only comes after the above extract - this is what confuses me.  Is this statement true:  The Euler-Langrange equation is necessarily give a extremal function when fixed/natural boundary conditions are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sketched proof:*

1. Assume that $y$ is stationary so that LHS. of eq. (15) vanishes.
2. Start by considering $\eta$ that vanishes on the boundary. Then the first term on the RHS. of eq. (15) vanish. From the [fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations), it follows from that the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are satisfies on the open interval $]a,b[$, which by continuity can be extended to the closed interval $[a,b]$.
3. Consider next $\eta$ that not necessarily vanishes at $x=a$ but vanishes at $x=b$. However, the second term on the RHS. of eq. (15) is still zero, cf. part 2. Therefore the first term must vanish as well. This can only happen in $2$ ways:

   1. fixed endpoint/essential/Dirichlet boundary condition at $x=a$, or
   2. natural boundary condition at $x=a$.
4. There is a similar conclusion for the boundary condition at $x=b$. $\Box$